# Data not saved according to Schema in mongoDB

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express, mongoose-schema

**I am trying to make an inventory management app and I created a schema for mongoDB through mongoose that looks like this**

```
  const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const Product = mongoose.model(
    "Product",
    new mongoose.Schema({  
      id: Number,
      barcode: String,
      ProductName: String,
      Price: Number,
      Quantity: Number    
       })
    );

    module.exports = Product;
```

when I try to save it through a React form it sends the data according to the schema. And the console log looks like this

[Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJWSQ.png)

but the data is not entirely saved only Id and barcode are saved but the other elements are not saved. the data looks like this
[data that has been saved as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zGy8o.png)

I think there is a problem with my server.js that is like this

```
    const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const cors = require("cors");
const dbConfig = require("./auth/config/db.config");

const app = express();
const { verifySignUp, authJwt } = require("./auth/middlewares");
const authController = require("./auth/controllers/auth.controller");
const userController = require("./auth/controllers/user.controller")


var corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000"
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));

// parse requests of content-type - application/json
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// parse requests of content-type - application/x-www-form-urlencoded
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const db = require("./auth/models");

db.mongoose
  .connect(`mongodb://${dbConfig.HOST}:${dbConfig.PORT}/${dbConfig.DB}`, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true
  })
  .then(() => {
    console.log("Successfully connect to MongoDB.");

  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error("Connection error", err);
    process.exit();
  });

// simple route
app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.json({ message: "cnct auth success!" });
});

// routes
require('./auth/routes/auth.routes')(app);
require('./auth/routes/user.routes')(app);
require('./InventoryManager/routes/store.routes')(app);

// set port, listen for requests
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;
app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}.`);
});
```

Can anyone help me with this I am really trying to solve this for 2 days, The help would be appreciated. If anything else required to take look at please ask and help. Thank YOU in Advance

Comment: show the server code where you are handling the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object you want to save

```
      id: ,
      barcode: ,
      productName: ,
      price: ,
      quantity:
```

The Mongoose schema is different:

```
      id: Number,
      barcode: String,
      ProductName: String,
      Price: Number,
      Quantity: Number
```

`ProductName`, `Price`, `Quantity` don't present in your object (**case matters**), and these 3 fields aren't saved in your database.

You need to change your object according to your schema. It should be :

```
      id: 123,
      barcode: "barcode",
      ProductName: "name",
      Price: 100,
      Quantity: 2
```

(values are just example)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your schema is written with different type cases, for example:
"yourMongoField" to "YourMongoField".

You just need to update your schema to the example given below and everything should work fine.

```
id: Number,
barcode: String,
productName: String,
price: Number,
quantity: Number,
```

Comment: uhhhhh. I didn't see that. So silly and Dumb me